# Setting up Bloom filter with PyArrow

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

I'm writing some datasets to parquet using `pyarrow.parquet.write_to_dataset()`.
Now I'm trying to enable the bloom filter when writing (located in the metadata), but I can find no way to do this. I know in Spark you can do something like

```
spark.sql(“set parquet.filter.bloom.enabled=true”)
spark.sql(“set parquet.filter.columnindex.enabled=false”)
spark.sql(“set parquet.filter.stats.enabled=false”)
```

as done in [this thread](https://github.com/apache/hudi/issues/7117).

Is there a way to do this with PyArrow or some other library?

Currently I am writing the dataset with

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

pq.write_to_dataset(table=table,
                    root_path=output_file,
                    filesystem=fsys,
                    schema=schema
                    )
```

Comment: Spark uses parquet-mr (Java implementation of parquet).  Pyarrow uses parquet-c++.  I don't think the C++ implementation of parquet has bloom filter support: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1327